# merging a Named num into an existing data.frame

Tags: r, match, igraph, named

I am trying to merge Named Num values into an existing data.frame containing vector of equal names (and length). However the order in the data.frame is not the same order in the Named num so it is not correctly matching the value. I have been trying:

```
attr_B12$deg.bin<-deg_binary[match(names(deg_binary), attr_B12$Name)]
```

Where `attr_B12$deg.bin` is the new column I want to create in the existing data.frame (attr_B12),
`deg_binary` is the Named Num [1:95] object,
and
`attr_B12$Name` is the vector of names which should match with the names associated with the Named Num…

But when I look at the data.frame there are incorrect values associated to the `attr_B12$Name`).

Answer (score 0):

I dont't know if I get you right, but I would first try to use `sort()` to get both datasets into the same order (if there is a variable with the same values, preferably unique values).